# How do I display a div based on the referring page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm an amateur coder, for this new year I've taken up learning HTML5 and CSS3.

I'm currently facing a challenge, I have a single page html file (index.html). In the page there is an html form which has an action to a php file. Once the php file processes the form it directs the user back to index.html. What I would like to do is display a div at the top of my site that says "thanks for filing out the form!"

How do I do this? I assume we would make some sort of "if referral page is form.php then display div" but I don't know how to detect the referring page. Plus I don't know what language to use, I assume javascript. I would like to stay away from php because I don't want my single page html file to turn into a php file.

I hope this is clear
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know exact structure of your pages, I'm advicing you to use sessions and htaccess to allow php usage in html files.

In your php file right after processing write following:

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['submitted_msg'] = "You have submitted a form";
```

In your html file write this right where you wish a message to be displayed:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['submitted_msg'])) { ?>
<div><?php print($_SESSION['submitted_msg']);?></div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['submitted_msg']);} ?>
```

For this to function you will need a `.htaccess` file right in the root directory of your project. With following code inside:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Hope, this helps you and if you need some other way around please write more details.

**UPDATE 1: JavaScript method with Cookies enabled**

form.php

```
<?php
  # above is form processing...
  setcookie ("submit_message", 'thanks...', time()+3600, '/');
  header("Location: index.html");
  exit;
?>
```

index.html

```
   <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function readCookie(name)
    {
        var cookiename = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(cookiename) == 0) return c.substring(cookiename.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

function deleteCookie( name, path, domain ) 
{

   document.cookie=name+"="+((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
                                   ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var msg = '';
        if (readCookie('submit_message') != null)
        {
            msg = readCookie('submit_message');

            deleteCookie('submit_message','/');
        }
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '<div style="background:green">'+msg+'</div>';
    }
</script>

<div id="message">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you go to form php it redirects you to index.html and message is showen up, if you refresh message dissapears.

Good luck.

Comment: is there any way to do this with javascript?

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed to say the least! thanks for your time! I'm testing now.